# Is there a way to know how many total lines of code Stack Overflow has produced?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, code

Recently I saw an infographic called [Million Lines of Code](http://www.informationisbeautiful.net/visualizations/million-lines-of-code/) and I think it would be really cool if Stack Overflow could be on it. I am sure there are thousand upon thousand lines of code the Stack Overflow site itself.

Is there a way for Stack overflow to compile how many code blocks have been created on Stack Overflow and possibly spit out an estimate of how many lines there are? I am also a little curious how many lines of code the Stack Engine has :)

Comment: Yep, cool infographic indeed, would be nice to know our position there ;) And also the position for the Stack code engine itself. I like the mentions to `healthcare.gov`...

Comment: Would be fun to compare lines of code in Stack engine to lines of code in questions and answers ;p

Comment: Problem is many of those are copied from external sites (usually with proper attribution) and it's really hard to know that. Counting the actual, genuine, lines of code written manually by Stack Overflow users, is almost impossible mission.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd I also realized this as a problem and I'm glad you brought it up. In the end I think it's just nice to see an estimate but yeah I'm not entirely sure how we would handle that problem :[

And Molot's comment has peaked my interest as well :)

Comment: It's going to be uncountable for the reason @Sha brings up... and arguably, the result would not be meaningful even if it were possible, as it's not really a "code base" as such

Comment: Is it possible to get an idea through using queries? Just discovered [this](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/queries).